# Erro ao salvar no banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

gostaria de uma ajuda.

Quando tento salvar os registro, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> 23502: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

As chaves primárias não estão autoincremento, eu to usando uma function que gerar as chaves primárias pra mim. Meu código que to fazendo para salvar:

```
 public async Task Salvar(T obj)
    {
        Db.Set<T>().Add(obj);
        await Db.SaveChangesAsync();//TA DANDO ERRO AQUI
    }
```

Meu id já ta indo com um valor.

Comment: O erro diz que id está nulo. Provavelmente o erro está no código que você está usando pra gerar o id. Faz assim: antes de salvar, use um alert out outro código semelhante para escrever o valor do id na tela, aí você verifica se realmente está sendo criado.

Comment: Já fiz isso, o valor do id não está indo null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão o Entity Framework vai entender que a chave primária esta sendo gerada DatabaseGerated e ele vai ignorar o valor que você inserir manualmente como chave, você tem que especificar que não será:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

ou no caso do fluent:

```
Property(e => e.Id)
     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado, até que fim consegui gravar !!!!