# EntityFramework DatabaseGenerated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho uma propriedade no meu model onde gera automaticamente o Id quando é inserido no Db, porém tenho um caso específico onde preciso colocar o Id manualmente, existe alguma forma de impedir que o EF gere o Id automático, se eu criar e enviar o object com o Id fixo ele ignora e gera um novo.

A minha dúvida é: é possível ao salvar ter uma opção para ignorar a geração automática? Em um caso específico preciso disso, nos demais a geração deverá ser automática como está o código abaixo.
Apenas para esclarecer, o problema está no Seed do banco, onde eu preciso adicionar um usuário com Id fixo onde é relacionado com as propriedades e demais relacionamentos de outro sistema, nos demais serão gerados automaticamente
**portanto: eu não posso remover essa propriedade de geração automática do ID.**

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override Guid Id
    {
        get => base.Id;
        set => base.Id = value;
    }
```

Comment: Você tem que verificar se na base está sendo gerado automáticamente e remover isso de lá e no seu código retirar `DatabaseGenerated`...

Comment: Está sendo gerado automaticamente sim.. porém eu não posso remover do meu código.. eu preciso saber se há algum parâmetro opcional para ignorar a geração automática, pois é um caso específico onde preciso definir o Id, nos demais a geração é auto.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro ao salvar no banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233464/erro-ao-salvar-no-banco)

Comment: @gabrielcoletta não exatamente. eu vi esse post.

Comment: Thiago, essa configuração tem que ser removido da sua tabela e também do seu código é o que tem que ser feito .... Mesmo colocando None, a tabela vai gerar um novo identificador, apesar que acredito que essa sua duvida é muito estranho, visto que é um Guid, porque no caso em si quer controlar, não é melhor o banco e o orm?

Comment: eu editei o post.. acho que agora ficou mais claro.

Comment: Se é um caso especifico, implemente sua entidade separada e passe o `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel... realmente esse é o detalhe.. é um caso específico, se fosse padrão faria o que o Virgilio falou, para remover, mas não é.. por isso citei isso no início do problema na questão.. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. abs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você deve fazer é habilitar a capacidade de inserir valores explícitos na coluna identidade da sua tabela. Isso é feito pelo parâmetro

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABELA] {ON|OFF}
```

Imagine que temos o seguinte modelo:

```
public class Blog {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
}
```

O trecho do método que faz a inserção em seu banco deveria ficar assim:

```
if (blog.Titulo == tituloDeterminado) {
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
        blog.BlogId = valorDeterminado;
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blog] ON");
        _context.SaveChanges();
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blog] OFF");
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
else {
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

O trecho de código vai atribuir um determinado `valor` (variável `valorDeterminado`) sempre que o `titulo` for igual a um determinado valor (`tituloDeterminado`).

Entenda isso como um exemplo e não como uma solução final para o seu projeto. Adapte-o conforme a sua necessidade.

Fonte:

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql

Answer (score -3):

public class Blog {
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int BlogId { get; set; }
public string Titulo { get; set; }
}